# TypeError: Cannot call method 'child' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

New to angular and firebase. I am running into the error "TypeError: Cannot call method 'child' of undefined" on initial page load. It is undefined because it isn't ready yet, but I am unsure of how to handle the situation.

Scenario as follows:
1. User logs in
2. Firebase verifies user is logged in
3. User has a friends list of child 'friends'
4. Code tries to get child 'friends' before Firebase can verify the user

The code to login

```
    $rootScope.userRef = $rootScope.fireRef.child('users');
    $rootScope.authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient($rootScope.fireRef, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
        // an error occurred while attempting login
        console.log(error);
    } else if (user) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase              
        $rootScope.userData = $rootScope.userRef.child(user.id);
    } else {
        // user is logged out             
    }
});
```

Later, in the FriendsController when user is on /friends route

```
   var friendsList = $scope.userData.child('friends'); 
   var promise = angularFire(friendsList.limit(10), $scope, 'friends', {});
```

The error occurs on friendsList because the userData ref isn't ready (I think). Navigating to /friends from elsewhere doesn't have this issue, only on page load. I am looking for solutions to handle the scenario. Thank you.

Edit: additional suggestions I have tried based on the suggestions thus far from Kato and Anant.

Using a promise:

```
    var def = $q.defer();
    $rootScope.loginPromise = def.promise;
    // then in authclient
    def.resolve();
```

Then in friends controller:

```
    $rootScope.loginPromise.then(function() {
       var friendsList = $scope.userData.child('friends'); 
       var promise = angularFire(friendsList.limit(10), $scope, 'friends', {}); 
    });
```

This results in the friends list not loading. Interestingly, when I click a menu button then loginPromise runs. This is not what I would have expected. Any idea why this might be?

Use an observer model:

```
   $rootScope.broadcast('authenticated') // in user verification
```

In FriendsController:

```
    $rootScope.$on('authenticated', function() {
      var friendsList = $scope.userData.child('friends'); 
      var promise = angularFire(friendsList.limit(10), $scope, 'friends', {}); 
    });
```

This works on page load, but not if navigating to the page since there is no longer an event broadcast of 'authenticated'. So it seems this introduces another question. How to navigate to /friends so that the desired data loads?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait until the callback for authClient is fired, as you suspected. There are several solutions to this issue.

**Set a promise**

Since Angular will not care if $scope.friends is undefined, the simplest answer might be to simply be to [use a promise](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) in authClient and reference that before setting friends:

```
var def = $q.defer();
$rootScope.loginPromise = def.promise();
$rootScope.authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient($rootScope.fireRef, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
        // an error occurred while attempting login
        console.log(error);
    } else if (user) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase              
        $rootScope.userData = $rootScope.userRef.child(user.id);
        def.resolve();
    } else {
        // user is logged out             
    }
});

// FriendsController
$rootScope.loginPromise.then(function() {
   var friendsList = $scope.userData.child('friends'); 
   var promise = angularFire(friendsList.limit(10), $scope, 'friends', {}); 
});
```

**Use an observer model**

Another solution would be to use $rootScope.$broadcast to alert your controller when the auth is completed. Then your FriendsController could listen for the event and do its work accordingly:

```
$rootScope.$on('authenticated', function() {
   var friendsList = $scope.userData.child('friends'); 
   var promise = angularFire(friendsList.limit(10), $scope, 'friends', {}); 
});
```

**Abstract authentication**

Often you can simply handle authentication at the Route level and not have to deal with it in your controllers (making sure auth has taken place before they can reach the secured data).

**Use a library**

Check out the [angularFire repo](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire) for more examples of all of these and for a nice lib that can abstract much of this work.

Comment: I'd also recommend looking at the new authentication support added to angularFire, there's an overview on how to use it here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/D6wgBgUtK94/AygqI4oJ7b4J

Comment: Hi @Kato , thank you for the suggestions. I ran into some issues with promises and using an observer model and have edited my answer with my results. Perhaps you could help me with those. I also was not able to get angularFire authenticating but I will keep tinkering as I am learning a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @Anant following the instructions in the google group thread I was able to get the authentication going. Thanks for the instructions they were very helpful.